# what exactly does 'get_page_by_path' wordpress function do?

Tags: wordpress

I came across this wordpress build-in function 
**get_page_by_path**,

but I am still confused after reading 
the documentation,

can anyone explain better to me 
what does it exactly do and what value it returns ???

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `get_page_by_path()` eventually uses `get_page()` ([source here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L3146)), returning an object or array (depending on the second `$output` argument) representing a DB row from `wp_posts`.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page#Return_Values